# Page location for GridViewPager

Tags: wear-os

I would like to add small page location indicators (the small circles at the bottom of the screen) like the ones that is used for notifications in on the Android Wear for a GridViewPager.

What is the best way to do this? One small problem for me is that I use my GridViewPager in the vertical direction but I think that could be figured out.

Do I have to do this completely manually or is there any controls that would help?

**Edit:**
Added image of what I need for clarity.

[image: Image of small circles]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new version of Wearable comes with this feature.

All you have to do is update your dependency on build.gradle to:

```
 compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+"
```

and do the following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />

<android.support.wearable.view.DotsPageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/page_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and in your activity declare it like this:

```
 DotsPageIndicator dotsIndicator = (DotsPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);

 dotsIndicator.setPager(mViewPager);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved it. It might not be the best way but it works. If anyone have a better solution please edit this post or make a new post.

First I have a drawable that creates a round object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff"  />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="200dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="200dip"
        android:topRightRadius="200dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="200dip"/>
</shape>
```

Then in my layout I have created the following structure in my case I needed to have the dots vertically. But it's possible to create a horizontal version as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="15dp"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:id="@+id/dotlayout"
             android:orientation="vertical">
         </LinearLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
     <android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/pager">
     </android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to make the dots as similar as possible to the Google version. And I got it pretty close but not perfect since the distance between the dots are of by a pixel or two. I used buttons at the moment but it could be any view that you could make round perhaps images would be better:

I added the dots to my `dotlayout`

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDots; i++){
     Button b = new Button(this);
     configDot(b, 4, 2);
     dotLayout.addView(b);
}
```

Remember to make the starting button large:

```
configDot((Button) dotLayout.getChildAt(0), 6, 1);
```

And the Config method:

```
private void configDot(Button b, int size, int margin){
    b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundbutton));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getPxFromDp(size), getPxFromDp(size));
    p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
    p.setMargins(0, margin, 0, margin);
    b.setLayoutParams(p);
}
private int getPxFromDp(int dp){
    return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

On my pager i added a `onPageChangeListener` Where i reconfigure all the views to have the correct size.

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int i, int i2, float v, float v2, int i3, int i4) {}

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int i, int i2) {
           for(int j = 0; j < dotLayout.getChildCount(); j++){
               configDot((Button) dotLayout.getChildAt(j), 4, 2);
           }
           if(dotLayout.getChildCount() > i) {
                configDot((Button) dotLayout.getChildAt(i), 6, 1);
           }
      }

      @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {}
 });
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You got the right idea.

Check out `sdk/samples/android-20/wearable/JumpingJack` project.

[image][image]

Here is their layout for the indicator:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_0"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/full_10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indicator_1"
        android:src="@drawable/empty_10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the Activity:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        setIndicator(i);
    }
    ...
}

private void setIndicator(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            mFirstIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_10);
            mSecondIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_10);
            break;
        case 1:
            mFirstIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_10);
            mSecondIndicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.full_10);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is more or less the same thing that I did however I made it dynamic since I needed a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the GridViewPager effectively, you will need to implement a `GridPagerAdapter` (which you may have already done).  In the adapter, in your `instantiateItem`, make some changes based on the row or column number, depending on your layout. It could something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int col) {
        Log.d("test", "instantiateItem: row=" + row + " col=" + col);
        View v;

        // row == 0 for col scroll
        if(col == 0){
            v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.your_view, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
            // Change the textView text based on the row or column number
        } else {
            v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.your_other_view, null);
        }
        viewGroup.addView(v);
        return v;
    }
```

note: if you wanted the layouts across pages to be the same, but each to show the correct page number, you could do that too. Just inflate the same layout, but change their respective `textView` to the appropriate text.

Edit (responding to picture and clarification) Perhaps you could have a drawable resource of a small white dot. In your views, you add an array of said dots with a `LinearLayout` or `ListView` and, based on the column you're in, you scale the appropriate dot, using something like

```
// Read your drawable from somewhere
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.somedrawable);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
// Scale it to 50 x 50
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true));
// Set your new, scaled drawable "d"
```

Comment: Not completely sure that will get me the whole way. I still do not know how to create the small circles. Not sure if there is a control that I can use that looks like the notification circles. I added a images to my original post for clarity.